# How to mutate a variable in a tibble based on columns named as numbers in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a `tibble` with columns named as numbers (e.g. `1`). I created a function to compute differences between columns, but I don't know how to do it with that type of columns:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-r -->


    library(tidyverse)
    df <- tibble(`1` = c(1,2,3), `2` = c(2,4,6))

    # This works
    df %>%
      mutate(diff = `1` - `2`) 
    #> # A tibble: 3 x 3
    #>     `1`   `2`  diff
    #>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    #> 1     1     2    -1
    #> 2     2     4    -2
    #> 3     3     6    -3

    # But this doesn't
    calc_diffs <- function(x, y){
      df %>%
        mutate(diff := !!x - !!y)
    }

    calc_diffs(1, 2)
    #> # A tibble: 3 x 3
    #>     `1`   `2`  diff
    #>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    #> 1     1     2    -1
    #> 2     2     4    -1
    #> 3     3     6    -1

<sup>Created on 2020-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
```

Comment: One of: (1) if the columns are named as numbers for presentation later, than I suggest you keep them named "sanely" (i.e., leading alpha) and rename then to numbers-only just before rendering; or (2) if the number reflect actual counts, then I find it likely that the data *shape* is wrong: imo, column names should rarely if ever contain actual data in the name. This data might be shaped as `tibble(cnt = rep(1:2, each=3), val = c(1,2,3, 2,4,6))`, and process each using `group_by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert to a symbol and evaluate

```
calc_diffs <- function(x, y){
  df %>%
    mutate(diff := !! rlang::sym(x) - !!rlang::sym(y))
}
```

Then, we just pass a string as argument

```
calc_diffs("1", "2")
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#    `1`   `2`  diff
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2    -1
#2     2     4    -2
#3     3     6    -3
```

---

Column names are strings.  We could pass index to subset the column, but here the column name is an unusual name that starts with number.  So, either we can wrap it with backreference using `paste` or just pass a string, convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
> df <- tibble(`1` = c(1,2,3), `2` = c(2,4,6))
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    `1`   `2`
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     2     4
3     3     6
> calc_diffs <- function(x, y){
+   df %>%
+     mutate(diff = {{x}} - {{y}})
+ }
> calc_diffs(`1`,`2`)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
    `1`   `2`  diff
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2    -1
2     2     4    -2
3     3     6    -3
>
```